# My HTML website looks completely different on other users devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My html website looks so different on other devices, as in it looks perfect on mine, but when my friend opens the link, the containers are completely out of place and the images I have wont load. I really need this done and its messing me up.

This is the link to my website: 
http://webdev.edinburghcollege.ac.uk/~HNCSOFTSA5/effc/register.php

This is what my friend see's:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/485067625689514005/702930803574964296/unknown.png?width=1204&height=677)

And this is what i can see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjrjo.jpg

Once again, I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Right off the bat, it looks like the markup and CSS for `container2` is a little weird.

**Your HTML**

```
<div img="" src="fifepin.png" class="container2">
```

**Try this HTML**

```
<div class="container2">
```

**Your CSS**

```
.container2 {
    background-color: #595959;
    padding: 30px 60px;
    background: src="img/fifestad.jpg";
    background-position: auto;
    background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
}
```

**Try this CSS**

```
.container2 {
    background-color: #595959;
    padding: 30px 60px;
    background: url("img/fifestad.jpg"); /* reference is off */
    background-position: auto;
    background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You're missing your closing tag to your `<p>` on line 128**. This may be causing your unpredictable rendering issues on different browsers and devices.

There should also be white space after your placeholder attribute values in your input elements (line 78 and 86).

Also, the `align` attribute is obsolete. You should be using css to style whenever possible.

Try running your code through an [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to troubleshoot your many potential issues.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `head` if it's not there already:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
```